# While loop not ending

Tags: python

```
while playerhealth and monsterhealth > 0:
        x=raw_input('Attack or Run? >')
        if x=='Attack' or 'attack':
            print 'You attack the %r!' %monster
            if playerstats[2]>=monsterstats[3]:
                print 'You attack!'
                currmonhealth-=(playerstats[0]-monsterstats[2])
                print 'The monster attacks!'
                playerhealth-=(monsterstats[1]-playerstats[1])
                if monsterhealth<=0:
                    return 'The monster died!'
                if playerhealth<=0:
                    return 'You died!'
                print currmonhealth
                print playerhealth
            if monsterstats[2]<monsterstats[3]:
                print 'The monster attacks!'
                playerhealth-=(monsterstats[1]-playerstats[1])
                print 'You attack!'
                print currmonhealth
                print playerhealth
                currmonhealth-=(playerstats[0]-monsterstats[2])
                if monsterhealth<=0:
                    return 'The monster died!'
                if playerhealth<=0:
                    return 'You died!'
        elif x=='Run' or 'run':
            c=random.randint(0,1)
            if c==0:
                return 'You made it!'
            if c==1:
                print 'You didn\'t make it!'
                print 'The monster attacks!'
                playerhealth-=(monsterstats[1]-playerstats[1])
                if playerhealth<=0:
                    return 'You died!'
        else:
            print 'You can\'t do that!'
```

*Sorry about all this. When I try to run this it prints the monster's health and the player's health, but lets it drop below zero without ending the loop. Can anyone explaing what the issue why the loop isn't ending? *

Comment: I think that you want to change while playerhealth and monsterhealth > 0 to while playerhealth > 0 and monsterhealth > 0

Comment: You're decrementing and printing currmonhealth, but your loop condition tests the variable monsterhealth, which doesn't seem to be modified in your loop block

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use

```
playerhealth > 0 and monsterhealth > 0:
```

You code does not work because if `playerhealth < 0` and `monsterhealth > 0` your condition evaluates to `True`.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is with this line:

```
while playerhealth and monsterhealth > 0:
```

What it is doing is checking if the `playerhealth` variable has a non-zero value and if the `monsterhealth` is greater than 0. This is a [truth value](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#truth-value-testing) check.

You are missing a value check on the `playerhealth`. This will check if both values are above 0.

```
while playerhealth > 0 and monsterhealth > 0:
```